# Why is EF core ignoring my update to my dataset?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, sql-server-express, sql-update

I have a simple table (Table_A) with one text field, column_A. It's in a database with many other tables which I'm able to update perfectly well. (This table does not need to be related to any of the other tables.)

However, when I try and update any value in column_A, the code runs over it fine but does not implement a change. No error message.

I've tried editing the field directly and creating an object and updating that.

I've tried adding extra privileges in SQL Express but I can update other tables perfectly well. What could be wrong with this one table?

Here is the code which I'm using to do the update. It works fine on the other tables.

```
        using (var context  = new MyDBContext())
        {
            var ThingToUpdate = context.Table_A.FirstOrDefault();          
            ThingToUpdate.column_A = "Updated_Text"; // Update does not work.

            context.Table_A.FirstOrDefault().column_A = "Updated_Text"; // Update does not work.
            context.SaveChanges();   // no changes are saved

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my simple table was too simple. It was lacking a primary key.

As soon as I added a primary key, the updates went through. An error message would have been nice but never mind.